# R, AR(1) and FGLS Computations. Unable to create a lagged variable

Tags: r

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u14VG.png)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Aj1R.png)

Hello everyone. I have been tasked with trying to solve this problem for the past two weeks with little to no help from my professor. I am not really asking for the exact code, but I can't start the problem...

We are given a set of data of the variables (M,R,Y) and we are asked to run the regression shown in the image. My issue now is that I can't seem to create a lagged variable. I have been told that 1) we don't need to use time series objects 2) I should be using time series objects (based off my research). Furthermore, when we get to the part where it asks us to run the regression for t=2 and onwards to get the p_hat, the only coefficient I can get is 1.0000 and the B1 that we should be getting ends up being something like 3.14e-11, something incredibly wrong. Here is what I have currently for my variables, based off the data given. If anyone is able to help guide me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

```
#Creates Time Series Objects Which Can Be Lagged using lag()
Mt2 <- ts(data=DATA$M, start=1,end=180,frequency=1)
Mt1 <- ts(data=DATA$M, start=1,end=180,frequency=1)
Rt2 <- ts(data=DATA$R, start=1,end=180,frequency=1)
Yt2 <- ts(data=DATA$Y, start=1,end=180,frequency=1)

#Dependent Variable starts at t=2 and ends at t=181
#Lag Variable starts at t=1 and ends at t=180
Model_A <- lm( Mt2 ~ lag(Mt2,1) + Rt2  + Yt2, data=DATA)
bgtest(Model_A) #Conclude there is Autocorrelation

e <- resid(Model_A)
et <- ts(e,start=2,end=180,frequency=1)
et2 <- ts(e,start=1, end=179, frequency=1)
Model_e <- lm(et ~ et2)
```

Comment: Additionally, this is my first post, so if I could do something to improve the question please let me know.

Comment: Get rid of the weird [DATA thing, and post the question in the post body rather than in an off-site image, if at all possible. Show us what is in `DATA`  and tell us which column holds the time variable. Tell us what happens when you try to use `lag`. Or better still, provide a minimal working example so we can find out ourselves.

Comment: Also why are you so sure that your regression coefficients are way wrong? I can easily imagine many data sets where the value at t=1 is a very accurate predictor of the value at t=2.

Comment: 1. None of the columns hold a time variable, the attached image with the data is just what we are given in the problem set.

2. I know that my coefficients are very well off because the problem set tells us what our B1 coefficient should come out to if we did the problem correct. I will edit the body and try to make it better.

Comment: I fixed the "Data" at the beginning which shows a screenshot of some of the data we are working with. I am not certain how I would give you a minimal working example or the ability to use that data specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Using `lag()` inside a plain `lm()` formula does not work because `lag()` just shifts the time index but keeps the data vector unchanged. And as `lm()` (or more precisely `model.frame()`) ignores the time index, this leads to including the response variable as one of the regressors and hence a regression coefficient of 1. As an illustration:

```
lm(Nile ~ lag(Nile, -1))
## Call:
## lm(formula = Nile ~ lag(Nile, -1))
## 
## Coefficients:
##   (Intercept)  lag(Nile, -1)  
##    -1.819e-13      1.000e+00
```

There are various solutions to this problem, including:

- Using dedicated time series infrastructure such as `ar()` or `arima()`. The latter can also easily incorporate additional regressors via `xreg`:

  ```
  arima(Nile, c(1, 0, 0))
  ## Call:
  ## arima(x = Nile, order = c(1, 0, 0))
  ## 
  ## Coefficients:
  ##          ar1  intercept
  ##       0.5063   919.5685
  ## s.e.  0.0867    29.1410
  ## 
  ## sigma^2 estimated as 21125:  log likelihood = -639.95,  aic = 1285.9
  ```
- Using convenience interfaces to `lm()` with additional `model.frame`
  processing such as `dyn` or `dynlm`:

  ```
  library("dynlm")
  dynlm(Nile ~ L(Nile, 1))
  ## Time series regression with "ts" data:
  ## Start = 1872, End = 1970
  ## 
  ## Call:
  ## dynlm(formula = Nile ~ L(Nile, 1))
  ## 
  ## Coefficients:
  ## (Intercept)   L(Nile, 1)  
  ##    452.7668       0.5043
  ```
- Doing the lag pre-processing "by hand" before calling `lm()`:

  ```
  nile <- ts.intersect(Nile = Nile, NileLag = lag(Nile, -1))
  lm(Nile ~ NileLag, data = nile)
  ## Call:
  ## lm(formula = Nile ~ NileLag, data = nile)
  ## 
  ## Coefficients:
  ## (Intercept)      NileLag  
  ##    452.7668       0.5043
  ```

Depending on whether you need a particular estimation method or returned model class for further computations, one or the other strategy might be more handy. In your particular case I would recommend the last solution and then go through the different steps in the exercise by using plain `lm()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data.frame and create your lagged variable "by hand" or using something like dplyr::lag. Like this:

```
X <- 1:10
Xlag <- c(NA, X[1:9])
```

The base R lag function is not very useful for anything other than ts objects and they aren't very useful except for the specific modeling functions that support them.